# Why would MessageBox.Show show a blank message?

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0, xaf

I have the following code for a gallery control inside a user control that is used in an XAF Property editor.

I am using a MessageBox to troubleshoot why the OnPaint method sometimes fails.
However the MessageBox itself displays a blank message when it is located near the bottom of the screen.

```
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon;
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.Gallery;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp.Module.Win.Features.Jama.Editors.ThinWorkflow
{
    public class MyGalleryControl : GalleryControl
    {
        protected override GalleryControlGallery CreateGallery() { return new myGallery(this); }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnPaint(args);
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"In OnPaint:inner {ex.InnerException} :full:{ex.Message}", "MyGalleryControl:OnPaint");
                // throw new Exception("In OnPaint");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: OnPaint]

Comment: try just putting "hello, world" as the first parameter. It will show. Exceptions have a ton of data, and I'm sure you either hit some threshold, or it wrapped weird. You shouldn't be putting messageboxes in Paint routines, either. Paint could get called a bunch, and the user would have to keep dismissing them. It would be bad UX.

Comment: Yes "Hello World" works. The messagebox is temporary for debugging.

Comment: typically, if it is temporary and there is a lot of data to show, I would use `File.WriteAllText()` -- that way it's unobtrusive and easy to read if something goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens when the text is long enough to cause a line wrap off the screen.